# how to check version of cordova in an existing project

Tags: cordova, version

I only have the source code of a project. Is version mentioned in cordova.js is equivalant to cordova version used in the project?

Answer (score 1):

Try

> cordova platform version

It will give you the following output

```
Installed platforms: android 3.5.1, ios 3.5.0
Available platforms: amazon-fireos, blackberry10, browser, firefoxos
```

Also to know the version of cordodva cli try

```
cordova -v
```